# Особенности кэширования в Nginx

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Интересует тонкости системы кэширование nginx.
Можно ли при настройке кэширования всех php ответов делать исключения для некоторых запросов "на лету". Ну, например, в настройках  Nginx кэшируются все запросы к php, но  с помощью посылки заголовка Cache-control : no-cache или чего то подобного этот конкретный файл закэширован не будет?  Возможна ли такая гибкость?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ : с помощью заголовка X-Accel-Expires